# custom screen on top of caller screen in android

Tags: android

I am trying to launch my custom screen on top of caller screen that may contain fullScreen image of Caller and some buttons for actions like accept or reject call.
Using this code I can launch my application on top of almost every other application but not over caller screen What's the problem.

```
 Intent mainActivity=new Intent(this,
         PhoneCallActivity.class);
         mainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         startActivity(mainActivity);
         android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that call screen is overriding your Activity. you need to override the call screen.

You can override the call screen by putting delay before you start your activity.The delay will be around will be 500 ms and it can be less or greater that. You need to test it and check at which delay you are getting your desired result.

Comment: Gr8 answer but so late.. I've already solved it in the same way   Anyway thanX for your response.